# How to debug "Internal Server Error" in AWS Cloudformation (MWAA)

Tags: aws-cloudformation, mwaa

I try to deploy AWS MWAA via Cloudformation but come accross:

```
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: Internal server error (Service: Mwaa, Status Code: 500, Request ID: 21fea850-9cf7-4977-a947-d10dd3cc1a13)" (RequestToken: f2384bd0-68a6-44d3-d57d-fed3a52f817b, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)"
```

on the MWAA resource itself. The other ressources (LoadBalancer, Listener, etc...) are correctly deployed.

What are my solutions to debug this? Since the error message is not explicit and the resource is not created (so it has no logs).